# Is there a way to bind a command to fadeIn event without having to .trigger('fadeIn')?

Tags: jquery, events, bind

I have an interactive form system that has different modules, where the forms for each module is contained inside a different div element.  When i change from one module to another, I often do this:

```
$('#module_1').hide();
$('#module_2').fadeIn();
```

I like this, but now, after developing this system for some time, I have some functions (like re-initialize a jqgrid) that I want to happen every time a `fadeIn` occurs.  I set up this up like this:

```
$('#module_2').bind('fadeIn',function(){
    initialize_jqgrid();
});
```

Is there a way I can make this work for all instances of `$('#module_2').fadeIn();` without having to go to every instance and replace it with this?

```
$('#module_2').fadeIn().trigger('fadeIn');
```

The motivation behind this is just to have cleaner code, `$('#module_2').fadeIn().trigger('fadeIn');` is a little redundant.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure,

```
var _old = $.fn.fadeIn;

$.fn.fadeIn = function(){
    var self = this;
    return _old.apply(this,arguments).promise().done(function(){
        self.trigger("fadeIn");
    });
};

// and your code: // replace .bind with .on if jQuery 1.7+
​$("div").bind("fadeIn",function(){alert("worky");});

$("div").fadeIn(2000);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/gEVsX/2/

**Update for comment**

```
var _old = $.fn.fadeIn;

$.fn.fadeIn = function(){
    return _old.apply(this,arguments).trigger("fadeIn");
};

// and your code: // replace .bind with .on if jQuery 1.7+
​$("div").bind("fadeIn",function(){alert("worky");});

$("div").fadeIn(2000);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind -- Please replace `div#module_1` with `#module_1`, it is a much faster selector.

Comment: ~ yes in my code use the selector just referencing the ID, the `div#module_1` was just for an example.  I didn't realize it was faster without the `div` though, thanks!  I checked to make sure your function works with every `fadeIn` call, even on different divs, and it does!  see here: http://jsfiddle.net/gEVsX/3/.  Thanks a lot for that!

Comment: One more question, in your code, the `....promise().done(func...` does that make the trigger fire after the `fadeIn` is complete?  What if I want the trigger to fire at the beginning of `fadeIn`?

Comment: Yes, it waits till it is complete. If you want it to run at the beginning, run the trigger method either right after or right before the .apply line and remove .promise

Comment: Great, thanks, i tried it out, but i like your first method better!

Answer (score 1):

You could define your callback function and use it as a parameter to fadeIn().

```
function callback(){
    initialize_jqgrid();
}

$('div#module_2').fadeIn(duration,callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Function:

```
switch_module('div#module_1','div#module_2');


function switch_module(old_selector, new_selector){
    $(old_selector).hide();
    initialize_jqgrid();
    $(new_selector).fadeIn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback function `$('div#module_2').fadeIn(500, initialize_jqgrid);`

and put everything in a function with generic selector call;

```
function fadeModule(selector)
{
    $(selector).fadeIn(500, initialize_jqgrid);
}
```

And call it like that `fadeModule('div#module_2');`

EDIT: 500 is the default duration for a fadeIn, put whatever you want.

Comment: In your code, `initialize_jqGrid()` would be called immediately on that line, and then never again. Remove `()`