# bind commands to hide event without calling .trigger('hide');

Tags: jquery, html, hide, bind

Recently I asked a question, how to bind commands to `.fadeIn()` events without having to call `.trigger('fadeIn')` every time they are to be called.  I got a very good solution, in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336442/is-there-a-way-to-bind-a-command-to-fadein-event-without-having-to-triggerfad).

However I tried to do the same procedure for the `.hide()` event like this:

```
var _old = $.fn.hide;
$.fn.hide = function(){
    var self = this;
    _old.apply(this,arguments).promise().done(function(){
        self.trigger("hide");
    });
};
```

It seems to work in general, as is shown in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gEVsX/5/

But when I add this to the script, I am getting an error from a seemingly unrelated location.  It is being thrown from this section of script:

```
    $('#unique_div_id').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode",
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function(){
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

Which just initializes a div to be a modal dialog. I assume I am getting this error because I have messed up the jQuery hide code. I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined

I have replicated the error in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gEVsX/6/

Does anyone know how I can fix my `.hide()` function wrapper script?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Name your "new" `hide()` something else, like `rawHide()` etc, and keep the "old" `hide()` as is.

Comment: Oops, i fixed the answer noted in this question. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've broken the contract of the `hide()` method, which is suppsoed to be chainable.

You need to `return this;` from your new `hide()`.

Comment: That fixed the jsfiddle example, but unfortunately when I added the `return this;` to my page, now nothing shows up at all...  No errors

Comment: Use Firebug to see what elements are causing the problem.

Comment: I usually use Chrome to debug, I have firebug open now.  In chrome's dev tools there was no indication of an error, and same as far as I can tell in firebug.  The whole page is loading, and I put a break point in the `onLoad` function where I make the first UI visible, and it executes with no error, but nothing shows up.  If I take out the `.hide` wrapper, everything shows up and works fine.